# Dimmer capacity for halogen bulb

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, bulb, halogen

I bought a dimmer leviton decora
6672 sureslide. On the box I see next capacity 150W LED/CFL
600W Incandescent. Also on on the box I see that it can be used with halogen bulbs. What is the capacity for halogen bulbs?

Answer (score 2):

Halogen bulbs are technically incandescent bulbs. Therefore, the capacity would be 600 W according to the box.

According to [topbulb.com](http://www.topbulb.com/blog/whats-difference-halogen-incandescent-bulb/),

> Halogen bulbs are technically incandescent light bulbs – illumination is produced in both when a tungsten filament is heated sufficiently to emit light or “incandescence.” The difference between the two is in the composition of the glass envelope and the gas inside the envelope.